# Set OL padding back to default after reset

Tags: css

Somewhere resets ol's padding to 0

```
ol { padding:0; }
```

I need to set it back to default which padding is growing depends on the number

```
ol { /* ??? */ }
```

Uploaded here: http://jsfiddle.net/jGxLS/

**Preview:**

As you can see, the padding is not growing (overflow to the left):

[image]

How to make the padding grow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change the `list-style-position` to `inside`, then change the amount of padding to get the same amount of space as before:

```
ol {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This of course will break the alignment of the numbers against the text, but there isn't much you can do about that. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jGxLS/1/